# Insertion in preorder threaded binary search tree

Tags: c, tree, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal, preorder

I am having problem in insertion of keys in preorder threaded binary tree. Can someone help me with the implementation of insertion and traversals in preorder threaded binary tree.

Comment: Welcome to [SO].  What have you tried? We cannot help you write something from scratch but if you are having trouble with specific parts of the code we can help you.  Please read [ask] and [mcve] for more information

Comment: I'm just having a problem in inserting the right child of the preorder threaded binary tree.